# SQL Server 2008 - No result is return

Tags: sql-server-2008, return-value

I'm running the below script to test something but it seems it's not working. Is there a setting I need to turn on/off?

```
DECLARE @date datetime
DECLARE @dailyEnd varchar(12)
DECLARE @column varchar(100)
SET @date = '02 Jan 2012'
SET @dailyEnd = @date + 1
SET @column = 'D'+Convert(varchar(8), @date, 12)

print @date
print @dailyEnd
print @column
```

I don't see the values returned on screen, but only this message:

> Command(s) completed successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using SQL Server Management Studio, right? There are 2 tabs of output:

- Messages -- this is where you should see the output
- Results

Or, you may have set your query options to Parse Only. (Right-click your SQL and select Query Options.)

Comment: Hi John, Thank you for responding to my question. When I run the script only the result tab is return showing the message. I've checked that I don't have ParseOnly ticked.

Comment: Do you see any other query options that could be to blame, e.g., NOEXEC?

Comment: Maybe something's wrong with your current connection. Open a new connection and run the query there. Don't use Control-N, as that re-uses the current connection.

Comment: So what was the actual solution here?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this when I was inadvertently pressing Ctrl+F5 instead of F5 to execute a query.
My Mac at home had trained me to press Fn+F5 to execute queries over remote desktop and when I got to work Monday I started incorrectly pressing Ctrl+F5.

Answer (score 0):

You may have opened your query in ALTER mode, like I just did. I kept running the query, but all I was doing was altering my existing VIEW. Once I ran a query against the VIEW, I saw my Results in the grid.

Comment: Can you explain further how you actually change the mode?